# Как изменить положение радиопереключателя в меню?

Tags: java, android, меню

Как сделать, чтобы переключатели отображались слева от наименования и уменьшить расстояние?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_tiles"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_tiles"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_list"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_list"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</group>
</menu>
```

```js
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать кастомизировать следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_tiles"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_tiles"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        app:actionViewClass="my.package.MyCheckBox" <!-- внимание сюда -->
         />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_list"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_list"
        app:showAsAction="never" 
        app:actionViewClass="my.package.MyCheckBox"  <!-- внимание сюда -->
     />
</group>
</menu>
```

И написать свой класс `my.package.MyCheckBox` - очевидно он должен наследовать от `CheckBox`

Но предупрежу, что это путь героя, устланный тучей плохо документированных подробностей.

Так что удачного кодинга.

**Update**

Есть похоже способ попроще, применить:

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/my_check_layout"
```

и кастомизировать свой чекбокс на уровне xml

Comment: см. апдейт ответа